# How to act on both signal (communication clock) edges in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I wonder what would be "the best" or at least a "good" way to implement a process that acts on both eges on a bus or communication clock.

Assume you want to serve a FiFo which can send and receive Data. Usually the received data gets assigned on the "falling" edge of its bus "com_clk" where data that get send out need to be updatet on the rising edge of "com_clk" in order to be most stable when the counterpart assigns the data on the falling edge.

For this scenario i can think of multiple ways for the realisation but i cant evaluate how "good" they are in terms of hardware usage, robustness or synthesizeabillity, nor do i in gneneral know a good ressource to look something like this up.

My approaches look something like this, with the usual framework of course:

Approach 1:

```
wait until rising_edge(com_clk);
  if reading='1' then 
    wait until com_clk='0';
    internal_mem <= bus_data;  --read the data from the bus
  else
    bus_data <= internal_mem ; --write the data to the bus
  end if;
```

Approach 2:

```
wait until rising_edge(sys_clk);   --should be much faster than "clk" i guess about 10x(?)
  if reading='1' then 
    wait until com_clk='0';        --wait for the com_clk to become '0'
    internal_mem <= bus_data;      --read the data from the bus
  else
    wait until com_clk='1';        --wait for the com_clk to become '1'
    bus_data <= internal_mem ;     --write the data to the bus
  end if;
```

A derivation of Solution 2 would be to build a edge detector for "com_clk" and use that signal for the "wait until" or in a "if-clause". 
So what would be a "good" or "best" approach to act on both edges of the com_clk signal and how can i evaluate that on my own?

Comment: *"Usually the received data gets assigned on the "falling" edge of its bus "com_clk" where data that get send out need to be updatet on the rising edge of "com_clk" "* No that is **not the usual**. The usual is that everything runs from one clock edge. Clocking on both edges does not gain you anything as you might just as well use one edge with a clock which is twice as fast. The advantage is that your clock does not have to be exact 50/50.

Comment: i am pretty sure that i have read that now in several app notes and it makes a lot of sense in terms of signal to noise ratio. Clocking the data in while they are changing is imho not a good idea.

Comment: This is less a VHDL question, and more a design question. You can clock on both edges just fine in VHDL. Its just not possible to map that to an FPGA (and even its its an asic, not in the way you coded anyway). Clocking at 2x rate is pretty normal  - then you set the clock-data timings in your timing specs to enasure you maintain correct setup/hold time requirements.

Comment: Assuming you are trying to implement an UART-like functionality? In a usual FPGA implementation, such functionality is not triggered directly by the clock, but with derived signals that are used as enables. FPGAs typically do not have hardware that is able to trigger on both clock edges.

Comment: @Tricky 
I  only care about the implementation in VHDL so i would say the question is about VDHL only, and i dont want to clock on both edges, the core of the question really is how to make my way around that. When i get you right raising the sys_clk frequency above at least two times com_clk, building two edge detectors for com_clk and then selecting a action depending on the edge detectors states would would be one option. How can i ensure setup/hold times, are these a result of my architechture or a configurable parameter?

Comment: @mfro call it uart if you like, but you can break it down to the handling of the memory, which i thought was easier to work with in a example. The last part of my question describes exactly what you mean with "derived signals", doesnt it? Deriving the com_clk with an edge detector and acting in dependence of the states of the edge detector would be exactly what you mean, wont it?

Comment: @J.Doe If you care only about the VHDL, then you can simply use both rising and falling edge. This will not work on an FPGA, but if you dont care about that, then there is no problem.

Comment: @J.Doe Constraints are part of your FPGA project, in your SDC/XDC file for Quartus/Vivado, or UCF for ISE.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially want to do double data rate on an FPGA.

**The terrible way**: You can do two processes one working on rising edge and one working on falling edge. This may or may not synthesize depending on your technology and it may or may not synthesize to use a hardware flip flop.

**The bad way**: You can not your clock and use the rising edge of both. You are essentially working with two clock domains here. If your timing is off you may get metastability. You will need to do the usual metastability handling circuitry here.

**The better way**: Generate a slower clock. Create rising and falling edge pulses from your clock. Those pulses will be fed into the enable port of your flip flops.

Comment: thank you. So the first two of your way, the bad ones seem bad to me also. If only because with my yet limited knowledge about VHDL / FPGAs  i don't dare doing something asychronous or risking metastabillity. My code gets glitchy fast :(
Your better way is essentially one edge detector, a say two bit shift register looking at com_clk and setting a "falling_bit" and a rising_bit " when it sees "01" or "10". The processes clock has then to be at least twice as fast as the com_clk, do i get it right?

Comment: Edge detection can be done a few ways. I like a registered signal clock -> clockR. Then for fEdgePulse if clock = 0 and clockR = 1. And according to the Nyquist rate yes at least twice.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very helpful to me. Can you recomend some literature to me that covers the topic?